# Problems importing strings to form a path from a .csv file

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46760188/problems-opening-a-path-in-python) question I posted days ago, I haven't' get any replies yet and I suspect that the situation was not properly described, I made a simpler set up that would be easier to understand, and hopefully. get more attention from the experienced programmers!

I forgot to mention, I am running Python 2 on Jupyter

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

g_input_df = pd.read_csv('SetsLoc.csv')
URL=g_input_df.iloc[0,0]
c_input_df = pd.read_csv(URL)
c_input_df = c_input_df.set_index("Parameter")

root_path = c_input_df.loc["root_1"]
input_rel_path = c_input_df.loc["root_2"]
input_file_name = c_input_df.loc["file_name"]
```

This section reads from a .csv a list of paths, just one at a time, each one of them directing to another .csv file that contains the input for a simulation to be set-up using python.

The results from the above code can be tested here:

```
c_input_df
Value Parameter 
root_1  C:/SimpleTest/
root_2  Input/
file_name   Prop_1.csv

URL
'C:/SimpleTest/Sets/Set_1.csv'

root_path+input_rel_path+input_file_name
Value    C:/SimpleTest/Input/Prop_1.csv
dtype: object

Property_1 = pd.read_csv('C:/SimpleTest/Input/Prop_1.csv')
Property_1
height  weight
0   100 50
1   110 44
2   98  42
```

...on the other hand, if I try to use varibales to describe the file's path and name I get an error:

```
Property_1 = pd.read_csv(root_path+input_rel_path+input_file_name)
Property_1
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-1d5306b6bdb5> in <module>()
----> 1 Property_1 = pd.read_csv(root_path+input_rel_path+input_file_name)
      2 Property_1

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    653                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    654 
--> 655         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    656 
    657     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.pyc in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    390     compression = _infer_compression(filepath_or_buffer, compression)
    391     filepath_or_buffer, _, compression = get_filepath_or_buffer(
--> 392         filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression)
    393     kwds['compression'] = compression
    394 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.pyc in get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression)
    208     if not is_file_like(filepath_or_buffer):
    209         msg = "Invalid file path or buffer object type: {_type}"
--> 210         raise ValueError(msg.format(_type=type(filepath_or_buffer)))
    211 
    212     return filepath_or_buffer, None, compression

ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>}
```

I beleive that the problem resides in the way the parameters that make up the path and filenemae are read from the dataframe, is there any way to specify that those parameters are paths, or something similar that will avoid this problem?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: repr(root_path+input_rel_path+input_file_name) generates:                 
'Value    C:/SimpleTest/Input/Prop_1.csv\ndtype: object'  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does 'Value C:/SimpleTest/Input/Prop_1.csv\ndtype: object' give anyone a clue where the problem may be?

Comment: SetsLoc.csv just contains a list of path and file names: {Path_and_name
0 C:/SimpleTest/Sets/Set_1.csv
1 C:/SimpleTest/Sets/Set_2.csv
2 C:/SimpleTest/Sets/Set_3.csv}

Answer (score 0):

I posted the solution in the other question related to this post, in case someone wants to get a look:

[Problems opening a path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46760188/problems-opening-a-path-in-python)